# Jpeg not showing up in chrome but does on firefox

Tags: google-chrome, firefox

Im not great at this stuff so please help

I have 2 websites and created the same image file on both, now in chrome only one shows yet in firefox they both show

Its really got me baffled

Below you should see 2 test images

http://jsfiddle.net/gotanyglue/EX348/1/

```
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
```

I had to input code? but wont let me add image because im new so here is random code

Many thanks if any one can help

Comment: Hi there many thanks

I solved it, for some reason ABP (adblock plus) saw one as an advert and the other as a advert
Thanks Bogdan Costea
and every one else

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is in your environment.

On my computer they both show up in Firefox and Chrome as well.

Try testing on other computers too if you can.

Answer (score 0):

try to remove chrome, reboot your pc and then reinstall it! (if u want to keep your favorites, remember to create or do the login with the google account in the chrome settings). It should work!

Answer (score 0):

Seems there is no hotlinking allowed on `www.saveuwonga.com/advert/jpeg/*` check your .htaccess file.